# Percentage by year

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I have this dataset

```
Year  score count
2007 20 grade 2000
2006 20       2385
2006 20 grade 10
2006 20 grade_N 3
2005 40 grade 428 
2006 40 grade 815 
2006 40 grade_1 15
2006 40 grade 3 
...
```

Generated by

```
SEL years,
Score,
,count(0)
,100.0*count(0)/sum(count(*)) over () as pct
From table1
Group by 1,2
```

If I add a condition

Where years =2006 it gives me the right percentage

```
2006 20  73.8
2006 20 grade 0.0
...
```

But if I do not specify it, it returns lower number.
How can I determine percentage by year?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.
`sum(count(*)) over (partition by YEAR)`

Comment: Thank you. In case I wanted to select the percentage resulting from grade_N how should I do?

Comment: I can not say that i understand you. What is the meaning of grade_N here sir ? Is it count(*) column comes after score column ?

Comment: I would like to extract he percentage by year of some specific score, for example grade_N. It is just a name. I have tried using where and like, but it gives me a lower number.

Comment: You can add score column into your partition by like ```OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR,SCORE)```. It should group by your counts with year and score at the same time. By doing this you can calculate percentage for both your columns.

Comment: It gives me 100%for all the scores

Comment: It is probably because of your ```GROUP BY 1,2``` statement. For getting COUNT(*) you are already grouping your values with year and score so your query returns 1 for pct then 1*100=100. With clues you and community put together i think you can overcome your problem. If you can not please put your query into a dbfiddle link then share it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62426069/percentage-of-cases-based-on-a-condition I opened this new question to explain it