# Percentage of cases within a group by year

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I have this dataset:

```
Year   Grade  count 
2010    B2     1
2010    B      478
2010    B1     46
2010    B1     12 
2010    B1     2
2010    B2     612
2010    A1     160
2010    A1     8
...
```

I would like to determine for each year (in the example there is only 2010) the percentage of A1 and B1 over the total in that year, I.e.

478+46+12+2=538
Over the total of B (B1, B, B2) :1202

In order to get the percentage 45%.
Similarly for A. 
I think I should also use like to distinguish between B and A values.
How can I do?

Comment: @dnoeth, I have tried the code but it’ll gives me the following message : ordered analytical functions can not be nested.

Comment: Why did you accept a non-working answer? :-)

Comment: Because I could not test it but the code was supposed to do what I have been looking for. Since I have different values name I had to change it. I have opened a new question in order to explain what I am doing, using the right names and not an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SEL years,
Score,
,count(0)
,100.0*count(*) / 
Sum(Count(CASE WHEN grade LIKE '_1' THEN 1 end ))   -- A1 & B1
Over (PARTITION BY years, Substr(grade,1,1)) AS pct -- per A/B
From table1
Group by 1,2
```